# Is there a way to make the Enter key work with a Logitech K811 keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, macos

The key is labeled such that it looks like holding down fn and pressing Return will produce Enter (as with Apple’s keyboards). However, when I do that it only produces a regular Return.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use <kbd>fn</kbd> otherwise, you could simply remap it to behave like <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is easily doable using the free tool [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) — download and install it, then add a "Simple Modification" from `fn` to `keypad_enter`. If you want to only remap your external keyboard, then set the checkboxes in the Devices tab appropriately.

[image: Karabiner-Elements Preferences]

If you want to keep <kbd>fn</kbd>'s functionality, you need a more advanced remapping/macro utility such as [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) or [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/). I'm not aware of any free options in this realm (though they may exist) besides the full version of [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), which doesn't currently work on Sierra.

<kbd>fn</kbd> is not a typical modifier key, so it can't be captured in the same ways that the others (e.g. <kbd>⌥</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>) can. Because of this, there is no way I'm aware of to assign <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> to anything. However, using one of the tools I mentioned, you can easily assign another hotkey to do the same thing, for example, <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but what about the root issue? Shouldn’t it be able to produce Enter without remapping anything? I wonder whether this is a hardware or driver problem.

Comment: @MichaelTsai Basically, the way the keyboard is programmed, the fn key is purely internal — when you press it with an F1-12 key, it sends a single key press signal to the computer. If you were to program some custom firmware you could alter that behavior, but I don't think it's possible otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like you’re saying this is a hardware problem. The keyboard is sending the wrong signal.

Comment: @MichaelTsai Well, in that it has to do with the keyboard itself, yes, but it's more a design flaw than a hardware problem. I actually have the same keyboard, and it works the same way for me.

Comment: I see, so you don’t think it’s a defect in my particular unit? They just designed it not to support Enter? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelTsai Exactly. Unfortunate, but I'm pretty sure there's no way around it without hacking skills.

Comment: Maybe write to Logitech and ask for a firmware update?

Comment: I’ve written to their support. Will update if I hear anything interesting.

Comment: Logitech support said that it’s supposed to support Enter, so the fact that it isn’t working is a hardware problem. They sent me a replacement K811, but it has the same problem.

Comment: @MichaelTsai Sounds like they need to update the firmware then—now 3/3 of our sample size don't support it.

Comment: Logitech now says that “the problem is the Operating System. Chances that the FN+Return is no longer supported as Enter.” However, I think you were right that the fn key is internal. I also tested the keyboard back to OS X 10.10 and got the same results. So if it’s an OS issue, it’s not a recent one.

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelTsai I'm betting that this is a Logitech driver issue.  I have used the K811 for a couple of years and have had no problem with fn-return as enter (as well as the mappings for fn-arrow keys and fn-delete outlined in [this help document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)).

However, I just recently upgraded to Sierra (currently 10.12.6) and upgraded my Logitech options/firmware (v6.70.1030). Shortly after doing so, I realized that **fn-return no longer worked**.  The other fn mappings still do and, weirder still, **all** of the fn mappings work perfectly fine using my MacBook's built-in keyboard.

So, I opened up the **Keyboard Viewer** to see what was going on and the problem became obvious. When typing on the **Macbook's built-in keyboard**, the keyboard viewer shows the normal keyboard like so:.

[image: Built-in keyboard]

When you hold down the fn key, the return key turns into the Enter symbol (⌅) as expect.

However, as soon as you type **on the K811**, the keyboard viewer switches to **an extended keyboard (with numeric keypad)**:

[image: K811 keyboard]

In this configuration, the fn key has no effect on the Return key's symbol (or, obviously output).

My guess is that the Logitech firmware is incorrectly defining the keyboard type for the operating system.  I have filed a support ticket with Logitech (case #06038823) and will let you know what they say.

Comment: On my Mac, nothing happens in the Keyboard Viewer when I hold down the fn key. Also, dictation and Launch Bar do not recognize when it is tapped.